# Probability of intersecting events continuous in the probability of the events

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider two (dependent or independent) events A and B. It seems natural $P(A \cap B)$ is continuous in the sense that $P(A \cap B)$ does not "jump" if the probabilities of A and B are slightly changed. Is this true? Both for dependent and independent events A and B?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $$(A\cap B_1)\Delta(A\cap B_2)\subseteq B_1\Delta B_2\implies|P(A\cap B_1)-P(A\cap B_2)|\leqslant P(B_1\Delta B_2)$$

Comment: @Did wish you would post this as an answer; it is a very useful first step in characterizing the idea the OP seems to have in mind.